# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I try to forward a data to excel but received the subject error.

I want to combine some of excel files into one excel file. First I created all_info array in order to collect all data into.

```
all_info = []
```

After that I read every excel files. Excel files follows; sample1, sample2, and so on.

```
data = pd.read_excel('sample1.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

I add each excel files' data into all_info array with below.

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    all_info.append(data)
```

After I combine all data within all_info array, I executed below code but received the subject error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_info)
df.to_excel("all_info.xlsx")
```

You may see error details below.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-5bff7d788042> in <module>()
  1 df = pd.DataFrame(all_tweets)
----> 2 df.to_excel("all_info.xlsx")

 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, cols, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells)
1202         formatted_cells = formatter.get_formatted_cells()
1203         excel_writer.write_cells(formatted_cells, sheet_name,
-> 1204                                  startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
1205         if need_save:
1206             excel_writer.save()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.pyc in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol)
525             colletter = get_column_letter(startcol + cell.col + 1)
526             xcell = wks.cell("%s%s" % (colletter, startrow + cell.row + 1))
--> 527             xcell.value = _conv_value(cell.val)
528             style = None
529             if cell.style:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openpyxl/cell.pyc in _set_value(self, value)
339     def _set_value(self, value):
340         """Set the value and infer type and display options."""
--> 341         self.bind_value(value)
342 
343     value = property(_get_value, _set_value,

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openpyxl/cell.pyc in bind_value(self, value)
278     def bind_value(self, value):
279         """Given a value, infer type and display options."""
--> 280         self._data_type = self.data_type_for_value(value)
281         if value is None:
282             self.set_value_explicit('', self.TYPE_NULL)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openpyxl/cell.pyc in data_type_for_value(self, value)
260         elif isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time, datetime.timedelta)):
261             data_type = self.TYPE_NUMERIC
--> 262         elif not value:
263             data_type = self.TYPE_STRING
264         elif isinstance(value, basestring) and value[0] == '=':

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
674         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
675                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 676                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
677 
678     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. If 'data' is a pd.DataFrame and you iterate over range(0,len(data)) and then add data to your list 'all_info', you simply add the whole DataFrame 'data' i times to the list. Your DataFrame df = pd.DataFrame(all_info) is a Frame holding i times the DataFrame 'data'. That exporting does not work seems logical...

Comment: @user2532323 Sorry for that.  I try to get more clear now. Is it still confusing ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a single List with all of the columns of data?  Currently,  a list of dataframes is being created, one full dataframe for every row in the excel file that you loaded.

Comment: @leroyJr yes, I try to create a single list. I also collect all columns of data with above but I can not forward it into all_info.xlsx file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your input and output data are supposed to look like?  It's not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you maybe want to do something like this?

```
fnames = ['sample1.xls', 'sample2.xls']
all_info = [pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1') for f in fnames]
df = pd.concat(all_info)
df.to_excel("all_info.xlsx")
```

Here, all_info is a list of DataFrames, where each elements is holding the different Excel Data. Then they are concatenated into one DataFrame and saved to disk...